# How do I select rows which do not exists in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a report.

I have 2 tables :

1. student_list
2. transaction_list

Here's the rows included in those table

student_list

```
Stud_ID | Name
1       | Cat
2       | Dog
3       | Rabbit
```

transaction_list

```
Trans_ID | Stud_ID | Payment_Month
1        | 1       | January
2        | 1       | February
```

Now I want to select data from student_list which exists in transaction_list and combine it with data from student_list which do not exist in transaction_list where Payment_Month = "January"

I have tried this query

```
SELECT Name, Trans_ID, Payment_Month
FROM student_list s
LEFT JOIN transaction_list t
  ON t.Stud_ID = s.Stud_ID
WHERE Payment_Month = "January"
UNION
SELECT Name, Trans_ID, Payment_Month
FROM student_list s
LEFT JOIN transaction_list t
  ON t.Stud_ID = s.Stud_ID
WHERE t.Stud_ID IS NULL
```

And I got this

```
Name   | Trans_ID | Payment_Month
Cat    | 1        | January
Dog    | -        | -
Rabbit | -        | -
```

But when I change the Payment_Month value in the query to "March", I got this

```
Name   | Trans_ID | Payment_Month
Dog    | -        | -
Rabbit | -        | -
```

Not as I want it, because I'd like this

```
Name   | Trans_ID | Payment_Month
Cat    | -        | -
Dog    | -        | -
Rabbit | -        | -
```

Is there anyway I can get that?

Comment: Can you please provide your structure and some sample data by using http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Silly me, LEFT JOIN in MySQL IS an OUTER JOIN. I guess I like specifying it as the STANDARD does.

Comment: @Philipp Here is the code when I use ["January"](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5897/7), then here is the code when I use ["March"](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5897/8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, Trans_ID, Payment_Month
FROM student_list s
LEFT JOIN transaction_list t
  ON (t.Stud_ID = s.Stud_ID AND Payment_Month = "January")
UNION
SELECT Name, Trans_ID, Payment_Month
FROM student_list s
LEFT JOIN transaction_list t
  ON t.Stud_ID = s.Stud_ID
WHERE t.Stud_ID IS NULL
```

Try it like this. By using `WHERE` you are filtering by the actual result your query delivers, so if your `LEFT JOIN` delivers null but you are filtering on that column the row is removed from the resultset.

By putting the month into the `JOIN` condition it will just return null on this column (on the columns added by the `JOIN`) and keep the row in the resultset.

Comment: I'm trying to use your code, I can run it on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) but I can't use it on my database, it says "JOIN expression not supported", what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You are using an OUTER JOIN, so take advantage of it.

- `Outer joins` return all of the rows on one side of the join regardless of whether there is a match or not.
- Therefore, when you run a `PREDICATE` on the (**outer**) `QUERY`, you are **eliminating** the rows that would return the values you still want to see.

You could do something like the following:

```
SELECT Name, B.Trans_ID, Stud_ID B.Payment_Month
FROM student_list A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TRANS_ID, PAYMENT_MONTH, Stud_ID
                 FROM   transaction_list
                 WHERE  PAYMENT_MONTH = "January") B
ON A.Stud_ID = B.Stud_ID
```

It will return all the matches on ID where `transaction_list` is in January as well as the ones not matched in `student_list`.
TO be fair, you might have been wanting to eliminate duplicates in your query, so you can stil accomplish this in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: He was already using an outer join (left join is short for left outer join).

Comment: Ooh, my bad. Still some nuanses from MySQL I forget. Thanks

Comment: @clifton_h I can't use your code, it says "unknown B.Stud_ID"

Comment: add Stud_ID to select of the subquery, `LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT TRANS_ID, PAYMENT_MONTH, Stud_ID`

Comment: @G.Chiko oops, sorry about that...mobile phone OP. Yeah, whenever you reference an INNER QUERY's column in the outer query, it must be specified (`*` grabs all the columns).

Answer (score 0):

Try this;)

```
SELECT Name, COALESCE(Trans_ID, '-') AS Trans_ID, COALESCE(Payment_Month, '-') AS Payment_Month
FROM student_list s
LEFT JOIN transaction_list t
ON t.Stud_ID = s.Stud_ID
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM transaction_list tl WHERE tl.Stud_ID = t.Stud_ID AND tl.Payment_Month = 'January'
)
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e50c/2)

Comment: No no, it wasn't that I want. But it helps me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Philipp

This is the code that worked for me :

```
SELECT Stud_Name, Trans_ID, Payment_Month
FROM student_list s
LEFT JOIN transaction_list t
ON (t.Stud_ID = s.Stud_ID AND Payment_Month= "January")
UNION
SELECT Stud_Name, Trans_ID, Payment_Month
FROM student_list s
LEFT JOIN transaction_list t
ON t.Stud_ID = s.Stud_ID
WHERE t.Stud_ID IS NULL
```

Even if I change "January" to "March", it worked as well as I wanted.